# GA ecommerce custom dimension tracking with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics

We're using GA Universal with Enhanced Ecommerce. Our code is AngularJS. We track regular traffic successfully through GA and see the Ecommerce  TransactionID and Product data just fine. However, our Custom Dimensions aren't showing up. Here's an example of the request we send to GA (http below). The TransactionID and 2 Custom Dimensions are bolded. Thank you.

http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&_v=j29&a=360330434&t=pageview&_s=6&dl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FEnrollment%2F&dp=%2FEnrollmentSubmission%2FConfirmation&ul=en-us&de=ISO-8859-1&dt=Confirmation&sd=24-bit&sr=1600x900&vp=1583x815&je=1&fl=15.0%20r0&_u=OCCACEQWJ~&jid=&cid=1558817403.1410460866&tid=**UA-2768151-11**&cd1=**dev_WEB-30718**&cd2=**dev_WEB-30719**&z=75252272

Comment: These are just general custom dimensions on a pageview (tid is just your account id) not product level custom dimensions, so you should only see them if you've defined them and built a custom report/etc.

Comment: Thanks, lossleader. That was part of it. After switching the Scope to Session, it started working.